# Schedule garbage collections for multiple jvms on single server

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm

We have linux servers running about 200 microservices in java each, using c-groups for isolation for cpu and memory isolation. One  thing we have discovered is that java tends to require a full core of CPU to perform (major) garbage collection efficiently.

However obviously with 200 apps running and only 24 CPUs if they all decided to GC at the same time they would be limited by the c-groups. Since typical application CPU usage is relatively small (say about 15% of 1 cpu peak), it would be nice to find a way to ensure they don't all GC at the same time.

I'm looking into how we can schedule GCs so that each microserevice does not GC at the same time so that we can still run over 200 apps per host, but was wondering if anybody had some suggestions or experience on this topic before trying to re invent the wheel.

I found that there are command line methods that we can use, as well as using MBeans to actually trigger the GC, but read that it is not advised to do so as this will mess up the non-deterministic procedure java uses for GC.

Something that I'm thinking about is using performance metrics to monitor cpu, memory, and traffic to try and predict a GC, then if multiple are about to GC, perhaps we could trigger them one at a time, however this might be impractical or also bad idea.

We are running java 7, and 8.

Comment: It is vanishingly unlikely that 200 JVMs will all GC at the same time, or even a significant fraction of them.

Comment: have you actually observed that problem?

Comment: Nope we've not encountered the problem @the8472

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't schedule a GC, since it depends on the allocation rate - i.e. it depends on the load and application logic. Some garbage collectors try to control major GC duration, total time consumed by GC, but not the rate. There is no guarantee as well that an externally triggered GC (e.g. via MBean) will actually run, and if it will run it might be ran later then it was triggered.

As other guys pointed, it is a very rare possibility (you can calculate it by gathering an average period in seconds of a major GC from all of your apps and bulding a histogram) to face it under the "normal" load. Under the "heavy" load you'll likely face CPU shortage much earlier than a probable simultaneous GC from an increased allocation rate will happen - because you would need to have a "lot" (depending on the size of your objects) of "long"-living objects to pollute the old generation to trigger a major GC.